# issues with nextjs images from 3rd party

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, nextjs-image

So im running into 2 issues. First im using Firebase to authorize GitHub & Google logins, so im displaying the persons avatar as a profile image in my navigation bar. Now everything is working just fine in my code until I switch `<img>` to `<Image>` - then im getting these two errors:
[image]

[image]

Here is a snippet where I'm using the avatar:

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import { useAuth } from '@/lib/auth';
const DashboardShell = ({ children }) => {
      const { user, signout } = useAuth();
    
      return (
            <Link href="/account" passHref>
              <a>
                <Image
                  src={user?.photoUrl ?? ''}
                  width="96"
                  height="96"
                  alt="profile avatar"
                />
              </a>
            </Link>
      )
      
    }
```

Now when I use `img` instead of `Image`, the avatars show up and work. When I switch it to `Image` I get the errors, and I console.log'd the `user?.photoUrl` and it shows up as `undefined`, so I kept the console.log and switched back to `img` and I noticed that the console log shows undefined as soon as the page loads and then immediately logs the URL, so its logging undefined and the url.

It's almost like the next-image try's to load before the avatar URL is retrieved.

So my question is, is there is way to tell next/image to wait to load till the `user?.photoUrl` is retrieved/populated?

Also yes, I have image domains listed in my `next.config.js` file:
const path = require('path')

```
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')]
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['lh3.googleusercontent.com', 'avatars.githubusercontent.com'],
  },
}
```

I'm on `"next": "12.1.0",` and I'm running on Vercel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your image hostname problem has been solved with your latest config in `next.config.js`

To fix the 2nd problem which is the `undefined` image on `next/image`. You can have a separate image source check

```
import NextImage from 'next/image'
import { useAuth } from '@/lib/auth';

const Image = (props) => {
   if(props.src) {
      return <NextImage {...props}/>
   }
   
   //TODO: if the image source is not there, you can set a default source
   //const defaultSrc = "something"

   return <img {...props} src={defaultSrc}/>
}

const DashboardShell = ({ children }) => {
      const { user, signout } = useAuth();

      return (
            <Link href="/account" passHref>
              <a>
                <Image
                  src={user?.photoUrl}
                  width="96"
                  height="96"
                  alt="profile avatar"
                />
              </a>
            </Link>
      )
      
    }
```

Comment: I will test this later today, but will this display the defaultSrc image permanently or will it update as soon as the the return changes from undefined?

Comment: the component will be re-rendered once the source gets updated. If it does not work for you, you also can have `key={user?.photoUrl}` in `<Image .../>`, that will help you to force updating when key changes @RobbieC

Comment: You're welcome!~ One side note, you can have a  custom loader with any elements in that component too.

Answer (score 6):

For those who searched for correct `next/image` domains configuration of googleusercontent:

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "*.googleusercontent.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "**",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

And actually [next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#remote-patterns) describe this:

> Wildcard patterns can be used for both pathname and hostname and have
> the following syntax:
>
> * match a single path segment or subdomain
>
> ** match any number of path segments at the end or subdomains at the beginning

Comment: This would allow all content at googleusercontent.com which is generally any user-uploaded content, you might not want this. It seems Google uses an "/a" path for avatars, so if you only want to allow avatars, you could alter the pathname to `/a/**` ☺️

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the hostname that appeared during the error in your next.config.js file.
In your case the hostname appeared is : `'lh3.googleusercontent.com'`

Your next.config.js would be :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        domains:['lh3.googleusercontent.com']
      },
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

This would probably resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

If

```js
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "*.googleusercontent.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "**",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

doesn't work, try the funciton version:

```js
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  /**
   * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
   */
  const nextConfig = {
    images: {
      remotePatterns: [
        {
          protocol: "https",
          hostname: "*.googleusercontent.com",
          port: "",
          pathname: "**",
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  return nextConfig;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show placeholder image till the avatar is loaded

```
<Image
     src={user?.photoUrl || '/public/static/placeholderImg'}
     width="96"
     height="96"
     alt="profile avatar"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by adding this code in my profile page :

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { app } from "../firebaseConfig";

const ProfilePage = () => {
const auth = getAuth(app);
const user = auth.currentUser
  if (user !== null) {
    const displayName = user.displayName;
    const email = user.email;
    const photoURL = user.photoURL;
    const emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    const uid = user.uid;
 }
```

Source :

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile

And in my `img` :

```
<img
   src={user.photoURL} 
   alt="photo de profil"
   width={150}
   height={150}
   className="py-10 mx-auto"
/>
```

And this is my `next.config.js` file :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['lh3.googleusercontent.com']
  }
}
module.exports = nextConfig
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing the Next.js configuration file to look like this:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    images: {
        remotePatterns: [
          {
            protocol: "https",
            hostname: "*.googleusercontent.com",
            port: "",
            pathname: "**",
          },
        ]
    }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```